# Disable auto numbering in pandoc markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have  Markdown content that looks like this

```
(A) some text

(A) some more text

(A) and so on
```

I'm using pandoc to render this to PDF (`pandoc -o test.pdf test.md`).  This produces content that turns the `(A)`'s into an ordered list, with labels `(A), (B), (C)`.  I just want the literal `(A)` to be present three times in the output.

How can I disable the automatic list indexing functionality in pandoc markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the [`fancy_lists`](https://garrettgman.github.io/rmarkdown/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#lists) extension, and can be [disabled](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extensions) via

```
pandoc -o test.pdf --from markdown-fancy_lists test.md
```

i.e. transform from markdown, but turn off (-) "fancy_lists".

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.

1. Disable parsing of `(A)` as a list marker by backslash-escaping at least one parenthesis: `\(A)`, `(A\)`, or `\(A\)`.
2. Add an (empty) HTML comment between the items. That way pandoc treats the items as separate lists and starts to count again.

   ```markdown
   (A) some text

   <!-- -->

   (A) some more text
   ```

   This method produces single-item lists, which may or may not be what you want.
3. Turn of fancy lists as described by @Dave.